# Auth0 re-login after token expire does not display login window

Tags: auth0

I'm working with Auth0, I have a problem where after user token expire and user try to relogin, it doesn't redirect user to login window at all instead it just automatically logged in when user click on login link.

They are fine if I manually log out then re-login, then it will ask for authentication again.

I tried removing all the localstorage memory regarding the user but it still doesn't fix it.

```
export const expiredAtKey = 'expired_at';
export const uidKey = 'uid';
export const urlStateKey = 'urlState';

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
    auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
        clientID: environment.auth0ClientId,
        domain: environment.auth0Domain,
        responseType: 'token id_token',
        redirectUri: `${constants.ORIGIN_URL}/auth`,
        scope: 'openid email'
    });

    constructor(private router: Router,
                public dialog: MatDialog,
                private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    public handleAuthentication(): void {
        this.auth0.parseHash(this.handleAuthResult);
    }

    public login() {
        //I have tried to clear local storage everytime user call login to prevent this to happen, but it still skip the login window
        this.clearLocalStorage();
        localStorage.setItem(urlStateKey, location.pathname);
        this.auth0.authorize();
    };

    public signUp(email, password, cb) {
        this.auth0.signupAndAuthorize({
            email: email,
            password: password,
            connection: environment.auth0Connection
        }, cb);
    }

    public authenticated() {     
        const exp = localStorage.getItem(expiredAtKey);
        if (!exp) {
            return false;
        }
        const expiresAt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(expiredAtKey));
        return new Date().getTime() < expiresAt;
    };

    public logout() {
      this.clearLocalStorage();
      window.location.href = `https://${ environment.auth0Domain }/v2/logout?returnTo=${ constants.ORIGIN_URL }`;
    };

    public setSession(authResult): void {
        const idToken = jwtDecode(authResult.idToken);
        localStorage.setItem('idToken', authResult.idToken);
        localStorage.setItem(uidKey, idToken.email);
        localStorage.setItem('userId', idToken.sub);
        const expiresAt = JSON.stringify(idToken.exp * 1000);
    localStorage.setItem(expiredAtKey, expiresAt);
    }

    private handleAuthResult = (err, authResult) => {
        if (err) {
            if (!environment.production) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            if(err.errorDescription === "Please verify your email before logging in."){
                this.dialog.open(
                    ErrorDialogComponent,
                    { data: "Please verify your email before logging in."}
                );
                this.router.navigate(['/initiatives'])
            }else{
                this.dialog.open(
                    ErrorDialogComponent,
                    { data: "An error occurred while trying to authenticate. Please ensure private browsing is disabled and try again."}
                );
                this.router.navigate(['/initiatives'])
            }
        } else if (authResult && authResult.idToken && authResult.idToken !== 'undefined') { 
            this.setSession(authResult);
            const path = localStorage.getItem(urlStateKey);
            this.router.navigateByUrl(path);
        }
    };

    clearLocalStorage() {
        localStorage.removeItem(expiredAtKey);
        localStorage.removeItem(uidKey);
        localStorage.removeItem(urlStateKey);
        localStorage.removeItem('userId')
    }
}
```

I want user to do the authentication again after the token is expired.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to SSO cookie set in the server to maintain the session. To clear the server-side session, you need to redirect the user to **/logout** endpoint when token expires. The **logout** method does that. 
https://auth0.com/docs/sso/current/single-page-apps

Comment: I found the piece of code that makes the problem, which is on the auth0 configuration audience. I make other questions about it, do you mind to have a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55331233/auth-0-configuration-audience

Comment: The audience parameters represent the resource server (API identifier). If you provide this parameter, auth0 will authorize the user to access the resource server by issuing an access token. The signature algorithm for this token exists in the API settings. You should always use RS256 as the signature algorithm. https://auth0.com/docs/apis#signing-algorithms  By turning OIDC conformant flag for application, you can force the application to use RS256 algorithm. https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/intro#how-to-use-the-new-flows